# annotation-based field injection using SpEL

Tags: java, xml, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am reading a text book on Springs Dependency injection features.  The book has one example that i found difficult to replicate.  The book uses a configuration class that contains the desired values in private fields.  I was only able to make the application work by changing those fields to public.

The configuration class I used is

```
package com.annotation.testing;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("injectSimpleConfig")
public class InjectSimpleConfig {

   //these fields are private in the text book
   public String name="MyName";
   public int age=21;

}
```

my application

```
package com.annotation.testing;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service("injectSimpleSpel")
public class InjectSimpleSpel {

    @Value("#{injectSimpleConfig.name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("#{injectSimpleConfig.age+1}")
    private int age;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + name +"\n"
                +"Age: " + age;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:app-context-xml2.xml");
        ctx.refresh();
        InjectSimpleSpel om = (InjectSimpleSpel)ctx.getBean("injectSimpleSpel");
        System.out.println(om);
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

and the xml file (app-context-xml2.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.annotation.testing"/>
        <bean id="injectSimpleConfig" class="com.annotation.testing.InjectSimpleConfig"/>
        <bean id="injectSimpleSpel" class="com.annotation.testing.InjectSimpleSpel"/>


</beans>
```

My question is that, what changes do i need to make the application work with private fields in the configuration class?  Or, is the book wrong? should fields in the configuration class be public for the application to work?

Comment: I suspect that the configuration class should have getters and setters for the fields you want to use.

Comment: @MDeinum  The above application works as is.  I 'believe' that spring handles getters and setters internally.

Comment: Spring doesn't handle anything like that. If the fields are private and you don't have getters/setters they don't exist. Spring doesn't automagically generates those for you.

Comment: I tried the application with private fields and getters.  It works as expected.  However, the example in the book does not have setters or getters in the configuration class.  Also, the book does not show an XML file for the above example.  It assumes the reader would be able to generate it from current knowledge.  ( i was hoping to find an XML based solution)

Comment: When a field is private it generally has getters and setters (and I', assuming here the writers have a hint in the book somewhere about that, getters and setters are ommitted from code samples in books to save space).